# Show a div if textbox is empty ( ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

In my application, I am creating an object like this:

```
$scope.editphonenumbers = [];
```

On ng-click, push an object to it like this:

```
$scope.addEditPhone = function(){
    var person = {
        phoneno: "",
        name : ""
    };
    if($scope.editphonenumbers.length<3){
        $scope.editphonenumbers.push(person);
    }
    };
```

This phone numbers will show in ng-repeat:

```
<div  class="relativeWrap" ng-repeat="phone in editphonenumbers">
       <input placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="10" type="text" name="phonenumber[]" ng-model="phone.phoneno" >
                </div>
```

Now I need to show a div if any one of the textbox is empty.

I tried the following:

```
<div ng-show="checkPhoneSS();">Phone Number is Mandatory</div>

$scope.checkPhoneSS=function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.editphonenumbers, function(item) {
            if(item.phoneno==""){
                return true;
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

But this method is firing many times and showing more than real data count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen you are using angular.forEach wrong. You should not return anything from it because you actually can't (it was designed for iterating over arrays or objects and will always return the reference to the object you provided as argument.

```
<div ng-show="checkPhoneSS()">Phone Number is Mandatory</div>

$scope.checkPhoneSS = function () {
    return $scope.editphonenumbers.some(function (item) {
        return !item.phoneno || item.phoneno === '';
    });
};
```

**Why is this better ?** 
It uses the native *some* implementation which tests whether **any** of the values in the array pass the test passed in the function.

This means that if any of the values in *$scope.editphonenumbers* have the *phoneno* field empty (or undefined) then it will return true. If none have the result of some will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular `for` loop and you will break out of it at once:

```
var item;
for(var i=0,size=$scope.editphonenumbers.length; i<size; i++){
  item = $scope.editphonenumbers[i];
  if(item.phoneno=="") return true;
  return false;
};
```

`forEach` is convenient but you can't break out of it until it loops over the whole collection and the callback is called on each iteration.

Also my guess is that your example `return true` is never working since it returns result for the iteration callback.